# Dropbox can't create new app on the site

Tags: dropbox-api

I am trying to create new app on dropbox, but it do nothing when I click "Create App" button, I am new with this SDK and I try this first time, does anybody know this service work or not.

I am using this link to create app:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps/create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I work at Dropbox). We're currently investigating this issue and hope to have it resolved soon.

Comment: Hi Leah, when do you expect this to be fixed?  I am having the same problem.

Comment: Worst case, it should be fixed by tomorrow afternoon. Hopefully considerably sooner (a few hours from now). Sorry about this!

Comment: This should be fixed now.

Comment: ok thank you, I will remove question after team repair it then if this is temp bug

Comment: ok I see that is already worked for me. thank you guys. What do you think do we need this question here? or maybe I should drop it?

Comment: The problem happens again. Any help please